# Drive space maynot be showing correct values

Tags: linux, disk-space-utilization

The monitoring system we use shows several servers, related to the same application servers, are out of disk space. The application owner stated they cleared Gigs of data  but this change was not reflected.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/sdc1                            59G   56G  554M 100% /storage

$ sudo du -hs /storage
56G    /storage
```

The difference between Size and Used indicates there should be some free space. A few posts recommended that a reboot would correct this issue but it's been over a month with no maintenance window.

Is there another way to to update the percentage to confirm the disk space is free?

Another site/post suggested looking for deleted files still held by a process. None of those found are in the mount in question.

```
sudo lsof +L1
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NLINK   NODE NAME
tuned     1392 root    7u   REG  253,0     4096     0   8133 /tmp/*** (deleted)
gnome-she 5256  gdm   19u   REG  253,0    12288     0 701887 /tmp/*** (deleted)
pulseaudi 5693  gdm    6u   REG    0,4 67108864     0  32735 /memfd:*** (deleted)
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which FS type you are using, but in ext3/ext4 there is a 5% of space that will get reserved for special processes so that they can continue to run when diskspace is running low.

Thats why you only have 56GB of usable space on your FS

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about the 5% reservation.
I guess part of my real questions is: can I prove that the application manager deleted the data they said they did when it's not being reflected in available disk space.

Comment: Do you have a df -h prior to the application manager deleted that data?

Comment: @RunThor `can I prove that the application manager deleted the data they said they did` -  Why worry about proving them wrong from incomplete information.  Ask them for the names of the file(s) they deleted, and go see if they exist?  Perhaps they tried to delete something, and it didn't work?  It would be far easier to check if you know something specific they think they removed.

Comment: They also might have deleted data, while at the same time more data was also written elsewhere.

Comment: @Zoredache I'll reach back out to see what they removed. Usually it comes down to files they transferred and forgot to delete or logs they aren't rotating.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I guess I'm assuming that the application manager would be more awair, at least after being notified, that one of their disks was approaching full of how much they are writing to the disk.
Eventually I can expand the volume but I'm trying to discourage a habit of requesting more resources to solve all issues.